# Is there a way to send multiple GET requests in RestSharp at the same time?

Tags: c#, testing, get, restsharp

I am new to c# and RestSharp. I am currently testing APIs and I want to send multiple GET & PUT requests. Is there a way to import the parameters directly from an excel into the program and run all of them at once or simultaneously?

Any existing framework/code will be helpful for reference as well! Currently I have to manually input data in the parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;

namespace Postman
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("");
            client.Timeout = 500;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("", "");
            request.AddParameter("", "");
            request.AddParameter("", "");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            Console.Read();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're new, better not get intro concurrently calling an API (you can do it via Tasks, but ) First try to do it one after one. You can read the excel file (search about Iterop or NPOI) then use a for to make the requests

Comment: What is the actual question? Retrieve from Excel ? How to do multithreaded/async requests? These are different problems. Try them individually and then ask concrete question about the distinct problems.

Comment: Thanks J.Salas, that solves one problem. Thanks Ralf, can you please talk about mutithreaded requests? How can I send multiple requests simultaneously?

Comment: RestSharp seems to have an async interface. So read on async/await pattern. Then when you have understood that use Executeasync instead of Execute as in your example. And await the multiple responses you get from the multiple Executeasync calls until all are completed.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. I will read more about it and then get back to you. Just wanna make sure, when I send multiple Executeasync requests, do I have to manually enter the parameters for all the requests? Or should I use NPOI for that?

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of below for the Async rest sharp calls in a loop.  You'll have to work out how to obtain your excel parameters and create an object.

```
 foreach(var o in myObject)
  {
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.google.com/");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/usingmyparams", Method.Post);
        request.AddParameter("my1stparam", o.param1);
        request.AddParameter("my2stparam", o.param2);
        request.AddParameter("my3stparam", o.param3);
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var result = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        HttpStatusCode statusCode = result.StatusCode;
        int nStatusCode = (int)statusCode;

        if (nStatusCode == 200)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data posted successfully");
        }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks @A Houghton. I will try this and let you know how it goes.